# A tran cancelled in MngStd still exists

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions, ssms

I am trying to exec about the next query (see below) with the ManagentStudio. The query exec time starts to take long, I hit the red squared StopExecution button which is at the top of the ManStd window, the query stops being processed and its results get canceled. Then I issue a 'select @@trancount' statement and it shows there is an open transaction. Since I hit StopExecution, the transaction was to have been rolled back, right? Why am I recieving the message saying there is an open transaction and why does sp_lock show me there is a bunch of MyTable's RIDs under X lock? All actions are performed on SQL Server 2008(RTM)

```
Declare @i Integer = 1;
Begin transaction
    While @i <= 100000
    Begin
        Insert into MyTable
        Values(default);
        Set i+=1;
    End
Commit transaction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cancelling a query will not rollback the transaction by default. When you press the cancel button in SSMS or a timeout occurs during execution, the application or client API just sends an attention request to instruct SQL Server to stop executing the current batch. The transaction will remain active by default.

You can specify `SET XACT_ABORT ON` so that the attention event will also rollback the transaction. This is configurable in SSMS (Query-->Query Options--Advanced). An explicit `SET XACT_ABORT ON` and should be included in all stored procs with `BEGIN TRAN` too to avoid problems after a query timeout.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
DECLARE @i Integer = 1;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    WHILE @i <= 100000
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
        VALUES(default);
        SET i+=1;
    END
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Dan!